# Kendo UI Scheduler TimeZone issue

Tags: datetime, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

On creation of an new event, the data is getting stored and fetched appropriately from db. However, kendo ui scheduler does not show that properly. For instance, I created an event for "2016-10-31 09:00:00.000", which is shown on UI in "2016-10-30 10:00 PM". I verified the value which is returned by the service, it comes as 1477864800000, and on console it is getting printed as "Mon Oct 31 2016 09:00:00 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)".

Please advice, where all I need to mentioned **timezone: "Etc/UTC"**, or what can be going wrong in my JS code.

```
            $(function () {
                    $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
                        date: new Date(),            
                        height: 600,
                        views: [
                          "day",
                          { type: "week", selected: true },
                          "month"
                        ],
                        editable: {
                            template: $("#customEditorTemplate").html(),
                        },
                        timezone: "Etc/UTC",
                        error: error_handler,            
                        dataSource: {
                            timezone: "Etc/UTC",
                            batch: true,                
                            transport: {
                                read: {
                                    url: "GetCalendarEvents",
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    dateType: "json"
                                },
                                update: {
                                    url: "UpdateCalendarEvent",
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    dataType: "json"
                                },
                                create: {
                                    url: "InsertCalendarEvent",
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    dataType: "json"
                                },
                                destroy: {
                                    url: "DeleteCalendarEvent",
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    dataType: "json"
                                },
                                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                    if (operation === "read") {
                                        var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");

                                        var result = {
                                            CreatedDate: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() - 6, new Date().getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                                            EndDate: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() + 6, new Date().getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0),
                                            Creator: 1378 // ToDo::                                
                                        }

                                        return { models: kendo.stringify(result) };
                                    }

                                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    "id": "EventID",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "EventID": {
                                            "type": "number"
                                        },
                                        "InteractionID":{
                                            "type":"number"
                                        },
                                        "title": {
                                            "from": "Subject",
                                            "validation": { required: true }
                                        },
                                        "description": {
                                            "from": "Content"
                                        },
                                        "start": {
                                            "from": "CreatedDate",
                                            "type": "date"
                                        },
                                        "end": {
                                            "from": "EndDate",
                                            "type": "date"
                                        },
                                        "ownerId": {
                                            "from": "Creator",
                                            "type": "number"
                                        },
                                        "location": {
                                            "from": "Location",
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "Attendees": {
                                            "type": "object"
                                        },
                                        "startTimezone": {
                                            "defaultValue": "Etc/UTC"
                                        },
                                        "endTimezone": {
                                            "defaultValue": "Etc/UTC"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Comment: Is there any time zone conversion logic being applied server side?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not doing any conversion, the following is the c# code: EventModel eventModel = CommonLogic.JsonDeserializeObject<List<EventModel>>(models)[0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the CreatedDate and EndDate in UTC format in entity class.

```
    private System.DateTime _endDate;
    public DateTime EndDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _endDate;
        }
        set
        {
            _endDate = new DateTime(value.Value.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        }
    }
```

Also, setting the timeZone in DataSource and Schema is not required. Just at Scheduler level should be fine.

Hope that helps.